# mvc multiple models in view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am making an MVC application. I am creating a View that uses a ViewModel and also use database entities in this view passed by the controller.
Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddGroup(AddGroupViewModel model)
        {
            ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities=new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
            return View(entities.Subjects.ToList());
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddGroupViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string subject_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number of Groups")]
    public int qty { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my view:

```
@model List<ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Classes.Subject>
@model ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.AddGroupViewModel 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Groups";
}

<h2>Add Groups to subjects</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddGroup", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create new groups.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> listItems1 = new List<SelectListItem>();

        }
        @foreach (var subject in Model)
        {
            listItems1.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = subject.name,
                Value = subject.name,
                Selected = true
            });
        }
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.subject_name, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.subject_name, listItems1, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.qty, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.qty, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As you see, I am trying to use two models in my view. But gives an exception (well how to distinguish them). How do I combine those two models in a view?
**Edit:**
So I did what suggested in answer, but now I get such exception:

```
{"The class 'ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.Subject' has no parameterless constructor."}
```

The class looks like this:

```
namespace ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Subject
    {
        private int v;
        private int userid;

        public Subject(int v, int userid, string name)
        {
            this.class_id = v;
            this.user_id = userid;
            this.name = name;
        }


        public int class_id { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public virtual Subjects_Users Subjects_Users { get; set; }
        public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Create a property on `AddGroupViewModel` of type `List<ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Classes.Subject>`?  Or create a view model which has properties of these two types and use that?  You can use only one type, but you can customize that type however you like.

Comment: @David yeah, but how do I get passed data from database (passed in controller)?

Comment: From the `entities` object that you already have and already use to get data...

Comment: @David please see the edit

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue.  Is Entity Framework throwing that exception?  I'd always thought that Entity Framework classes needed parameterless constructors for the framework to use them, though I could be mistaken on that.

Comment: @David the error says 'An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code'

Comment: Definitely an Entity Framework error then, you'd probably get better responses with an entirely new question since this one has already been answered and the issue is unrelated to ASP.NET MVC in any way.  I *suspect* that your entity simply needs a parameterless constructor, and don't really see how you got this far without one.  Though I'm not enough of an Entity Framework expert to really speak to that.

Comment: @David Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a view model, I'd use that:

```
@model ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.AddGroupViewModel
```

And simply add a property to that view model for the collection you also want to use:

```
public class AddGroupViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string subject_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number of Groups")]
    public int qty { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply create an instance of that from your controller to send to the view:

```
var entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
var model = new AddGroupViewModel();
model.Subjects = entities.Subjects.ToList();
// set your other properties too?
return View(model);
```

Then in the view simply refer to the property on the `Model` instead of the model itself when you need that collection:

```
@foreach (var subject in Model.Subjects)
```

Basically, while you can use only one type for your model (since there's only one `Model` property available to the view in the framework), that type can be anything you like, even a custom view model type that you define.